# explicit answer of and initial condition ODE with delta input

Tags: differential-equations

Assume this initial value problem ODE with constant coefficient:

$\mathcal{D}[u] = \sum_{n=0}^N {a_n u^{(n)}}=0$

$u(0)=u_0\hspace{0.2cm} ;\hspace{0.2cm} u'(0)=u_1\hspace{0.2cm} ;\hspace{0.2cm} ... \hspace{0.2cm} ;\hspace{0.2cm} u^{(n-1)}(0)=u_{(n-1)} $

I want to explicitly find the answer of the a delta function input given that I know the answer of homogeneous input that satisfies the initial conditions (that I will call $g$). i.e. I want to find the answer of the following equation in a piece-wise manner of $t<t_0$ and $t>t_0$ :

$\mathcal{D}[u] = \sum_{n=0}^N {a_n u^{(n)}}= f_0 \delta(t-t_0)$

$u(0)=u_0\hspace{0.2cm} ;\hspace{0.2cm} u'(0)=u_1\hspace{0.2cm} ;\hspace{0.2cm} ... \hspace{0.2cm} ;\hspace{0.2cm} u^{(n-1)}(0)=u_{n-1} $

Knowing that the input is *active* only at $t=t_0$, it's just fine  to express the first part of answer($t<t_0$) exactly as $g(t<t_0)$. For the second part, I want to use again the same $g$ only with different initial conditions (now at $t=t_0$ instead of 0).

To do so, I can integrate the ODE over and infinitesimal interval $(t_0-\epsilon,t_0+\epsilon)$ which yields the following constraints on the new initial conditions:

$ \sum_{n=1}^N a_n  \big[u^{(n-1)} (t_0^+)-u^{(n-1)} (t_0^-)\big] = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n  c_{n-1} = f_0$

where $c_i$s are the discontinuities (shifts) on each derivatives at $t=t_0$. and since $u^{(n-1)} (t_0^-)=g^{(n-1)}(t_0)$, then

$ \sum_{n=1}^N a_n u^{(n-1)} (t_0^+) = C$

where C is a linear combination of the same derivatives at $t=t_0^-$ and also $f_0$ and now I can rewrite my new initial conditions as follows:

$u(t_0^+)=g(t_0^+)\hspace{0.3cm};\hspace{0.3cm} u'(t_0^+)=g'(t_0^+)+c_1\hspace{0.3cm} ;\hspace{0.3cm} ... \hspace{0.3cm} ;\hspace{0.3cm} u^{(n-1)}(t_0^+)=g^{(n-1)}(t_0^+)+c_{n-1} $

Now, I'm wondering if this additional constraint prevents me to find a unique answer for the second part since now, it seems that I've got to chose the amount of *shift* each derivative undergoes.

Comment: The shift only happens in the highest order initial data $u^{(N-1)}(t_0^+) = (C - \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} a_n u^{(n-1)}(t_0^+))/a_{N-1} = g^{(N-1)}(t_0^+) + c$, with $c$ determined by $C$. If you include discontinuities in lower order derivatives of $u$, then $\mathcal{D}[u]$ will have unwanted contributions from higher derivatives of the $\delta$-function, like $\delta'(t-t_0)$, $\delta''(t-t_0)$, etc.

Comment: why is that so? can you give me a reference?

Comment: Option 1: The function $a_- \frac{t^k}{k!} \Theta(-t) + a_+ \frac{t^k}{k!} \Theta(t)$ models a discontinuity of $(a_+-a_-)$ in the $k$th derivative, but not in any of the lower derivatives. Take too many derivatives, you get $\delta(t)$, $\delta'(t)$, etc. Option 2: Reduce on $n$th order equation to a system of $1$st order equations. Use the usual rule that the discontinuity appears only in the first order derivative. Convert the solution back to the original equation. You'll get the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

One can obtain an explicit answer using the Laplace transform:
$$U=F/P+Q/P,$$
where $U$ is the Laplace transform of $u$, $P=\sum_{k=0}^Na_kz^k$, 
$F=e^{-t_0z}$ is the Laplace transform of the delta-dunction,
and $$Q(z)=u_0z^{N-1}+(u_1+a_{N-1}u_0)z^{N-2}+\ldots +(u_{N-1}+a_{N-1}u_{N-2}+\ldots+a_2u_1+a_1u_0).$$
This is an "explicit form" because the inverse Laplace transform of a rational function
can be computed by partial fraction decomposition. To do this, you need to factor $P$. But this is unavoidable with any form of the solution, even for the homogeneous equation. But if you cannot factor $P$, you still obtain an "explicit answer", in the form of an integral.

Comment: I believe that having the function $g$ known, as stated in my question, is equivalent to being able to factor $P$. My problem is, as you stated as well, this explicit answer, indeed contains the ICs and I don't know how to compute this ICs just after the impulse input.